# How to add facebook like button ,linkedin share button and twitter tweet button for each link on a page?

Tags: html, twitter, facebook-like, linkedin-api

I have gone through many questions already asked about this problem but i didn't really get any clear solution.. I am building a web-site using asp.net and i have several links on a page. I need facebook like button, linkedin share button and twitter tweet button below each link. How can i achieve multiple buttons efficiently without much page load problem..
Also is there a way to know that the user has clicked the button and successfully liked a link...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My two cents

Facebook button

In the HTML tag

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Right after the body tag

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=<YOUR APP ID HERE!!>";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Where your link is

```
<fb:like href="<% Response.Write(Server.UrlEncode(linkURL)); %>" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true"></fb:like>
```

Linked in

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/Share" data-url="<% Response.Write(Server.UrlEncode(linkURL)); %>" data-counter="right"></script>
```

Twitter

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<% Response.Write(Server.UrlEncode(linkURL)); %>" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Essentially you just set the link url to the variable linkURL so that it will print it out to the webpage.
I may be wrong, if I am please let me know and I will help you.

Comment: I did it the way uv listed above.. the buttons are showing.. but there is one problem.. it works fine when i gave the data-url.. but when i am dynamically assigning the data-url from code-behind it is causing problem.. the button disappers when clicked.. its quiet wierd and i dont get it.. can you please help..

Comment: Does this apply to all of the buttons? What is a typical linkURL value?  Also in addition, before you print the text string linkURL. Pull it trought Server.UrlEncode(); which should fix a few problems in some browsers. What browser are you using, BTW?

Comment: No, linkedin and twitter buttons are working fine.. the problem is only with the facebook button.. for example (linkURL = "http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNHZtva7n5Hd-1W7tGYSwoHLnvc7AA&url=http://zeenews.india.com/news/delhi/bjp-wins-north-delhi-mcd-elections_770339.html";) i tried doing Server.UrlEncode(); but it doesnt change anything.. i am using chrome.. i tried it with firefox also but with the same result..

Comment: Do you have a Facebook App ID and inserted it into <YOUR APP ID HERE!!>? You can create an app here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ Not sure if you may like an external site thought?